# Can pip work for both python2.x and python3.x on the same computer?

Tags: python, pip, blender

I need a certain Python library (namely [Blender](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_7/)) which [only works for Python3.x](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/302/how-to-change-the-python-version-that-blender-uses)

This is going to mean installing `numpy` for Python 3.  I get

```
Python 3.2.3 (default, Sep 25 2013, 19:36:10) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

Right now it only works for my `2.7`
Is it possible to install `pip` so that it works for both Python 2.7 and Python 3 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can ask python to run pip module as a script

```
python -m pip --help
python3 -m pip install whatever
```